# How can I use gesture detector with icons:[]

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

Here is my code where I am trying to put gesture detector on icons

```
    child: Container(
                                      child: SimpleAccountMenu(

                                        icons: [
                                          
                                          Icon(Icons.notifications),
                                          Icon(Icons.lock),
                                          Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                                        ],
                                        iconColor: Colors.white,
                                        onChange: (index) {
                                          print(index);
                                        }, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      )),
```

Comment: have you tried wrapped on a InkWell, InkResponse or GestureDetector?

Comment: yes I tried but it shows error

Comment: and what's the error... could you post the error?

Comment: yes I show you just sec

Comment: If you "icons[]" specs Icon widgets then your code is not going to work. Icon is a Widget, so, instead of Icon, expect a list of Widgets and that's it, you can then wrap the icon or use IconButton

Comment: "message": "The element type 'GestureDetector' can't be assigned to the list type 'Icon'.",
 "

Comment: The element type 'IconButton' can't be assigned to the list type 'Icon'.

Comment: these errors are showing on both methods

Comment: that's why I explained to you. You're expecting a list of Icon and not a list of Widget. Post your SimpleAccountMenu class.

Comment: thank you I changed icon parameter list from icon to iconbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `IconButton` widget and give onPressed call back.

```
child: Container(
                                      child: SimpleAccountMenu(

                                        icons: [
                                          
                                          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {}),
                                          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.lock), onPressed: () {}),
                                          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up), onPressed: () {}),
                                        ],
                                        iconColor: Colors.white,
                                        onChange: (index) {
                                          print(index);
                                        }, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      )),
```

Comment: I try this method but it showing error on iconbutton.

Comment: your `icons` parameter may expect List of `Icon`. change it to List of `IconButton`

Comment: The element type 'IconButton' can't be assigned to the list type 'Icon'.

Comment: exactly my previous comment will solve the problem. just change your `icon` parameter of the `SimpleAccountMenu` constructer as `List<IconButton> `

Comment: okay Thank you soo mush you helped me alot